# Частота звука Java

Tags: аудио, java

Что можно использовать в Ява, чтобы проанализировать частоту звука? Т.е. например - если получили звук на вход с одной частотой - то установить одно значение, если с другое - то другое.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо реализовать преобразование Фурье. Почитайте готовый анализ, например, [тут](http://code.google.com/p/audio-analysis/source/browse/trunk/src/com/badlogic/audio/analysis)