# частота звука в Java

Tags: java, аудио

Ищу класс для определения частоты звука, снимаемого с микрофона.
Что-то вроде гитарного тюнера. 
На входе - сигнал с микрофона, или wav файл, к примеру.
На выходе которого будет какой-нить long с частотой звука, исключая всякие шумы и прочие тихие звуки.

Comment: А если частот на входе больше, чем одна? Советую почитать про Fast Fourier Transformation, чтобы определять частоты несинсоидального сигнала.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Частота звука Java](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18462/%d0%a7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0-java)